# Why MLC ssd has lower TBW than TLC?

Tags: computer-building, computer-architecture, hardware-selection

I have ssd's.

1. Crucial mx100 250GB: MLC, TBW 72.
2. Crucial mx200 250GB: MLC, TBW 80.
3. Adata sx8200Pro 250gb: TLC, TBW 160.

From many sources I learnt that MLC should last ~ 6-10 times more writes than TLC.

so why TLC based ssd has higer TBW than MLC ?

Comment: 1) Marketing said to change the spec so it sells better. 2) An improved circuit design makes it perform better. 3) All of the above. 4) Ask the manufacturer, not a bunch of random people online.

Comment: Not a full answer: With cheaper bits, one can use more bits for ECC and have more reserved blocks that are not counted as part of the capacity while still providing cheaper advertised capacity. With large blocks, even relatively few extra bits can significantly increase coverage. There is also a possibility of better algorithms for detecting wear and correcting common/likely errors. Also marketing: Crucial might value brand strength more highly than Adata (e.g., 1 failure per billion within warranty vs. 1 in a million) or MLC buyers might care more about reliability → more conservative specs.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the release dates for Mx100 , Mx200 and sx8200pro , being 2014,2015 and 2020 respectively, Its mostly due to generational improvements in SSD industry. High TBW Nands like 3D NAND were still not widely available when MX100 and 200 were made.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).